# Calculate The Declining Balance Method For Depreciation?

Tags: code-review, finance

I have code generated by **AI Aria** in Opera browser

The code gives wrong answer only for: `Depreciation factor=1`?

```
assetValue=10000;
salvageValue=2000;
assetLife=5;
depreciationFactor=1;

decliningBalanceDepreciation[assetValue_, salvageValue_, assetLife_, depreciationFactor_] := Module[{bookValue = assetValue, depTable = {}}, 
AppendTo[
depTable, {"Year", "Beginning Book Value", "Depreciation Percent", 
"Depreciation Amount", "Accumulated Depreciation", 
"Ending Book Value"}];
Do[depreciation = 
Min[bookValue - salvageValue, 
 depreciationFactor*bookValue/assetLife];
accumulatedDepreciation = 
If[i == 1, depreciation, Last[depTable][[5]] + depreciation];
endingBookValue = Max[salvageValue, bookValue - depreciation];
AppendTo[
depTable, {i, bookValue, (depreciation/bookValue)*100, 
 depreciation, accumulatedDepreciation, endingBookValue}];
bookValue = endingBookValue;, {i, 1, assetLife}];
depTable]

Grid[decliningBalanceDepreciation[assetValue, salvageValue, assetLife, depreciationFactor], Frame -> All] //N
```

See below:

[image]

I use this [Calculator](https://www.calculator.net/depreciation-calculator.html?cmethod=declining&ccost=10%2C000&csalvage=2%2C000&cyears=5&cfactor=1.0&cround=yes&cpartical=no&cparticalmethod=halfmonth&startday=2024-01-14&caymonth=1&cayday=1&printit=0&x=Calculate) to compute values.

Where is the **mistake** in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Changing the depreciation to `depreciation = If[i == assetLife, bookValue - salvageValue, 
 Min[bookValue - salvageValue, depreciationFactor*bookValue/assetLife]]` gives the expected result for the last record in the table {{4096., 51.1719, 2096., 8000., 2000.}}

Comment: What was your question to AI Aria so that it generated this code?

Comment: @azerbajdzan "Generate code For Depreciation with Declining Balance  method ? With Asset cost=10000, Salvage Value=2000,Depreciation years=5 ,Depreciation factor=2, in Wolfram language ?"

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: So it looks that AI then found that link of the calculator and tried to translate JavaScript from that link into Wolfram language? Or you gave it also that link?

Comment: @azerbajdzan. I didn't provide any link. I don't know where AI got the code.

Comment: @vindobona. Thanks for correcting the code. You may write as an answer I vote up.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: It looks so because the labels of the table are exactly same as if copied from that link.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: This calculator https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/depreciation-declining-balance.php for example calculates the same Depreciation Amount of `819.20` for 5th year as in original code. So which calculator is correct now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150881/discussion-between-mariusz-iwaniuk-and-azerbajdzan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt at this. The function outputs a Dataset, which can of course be changed into lists of values as needed. I did not create the redundant entries in the data. For each year there is a year number, the beginning book value, the depreciation for that year (which will be subtracted from the book value for next years book value), and the accumulated depreciation as of the end of the year.

```
decliningBalanceDepreciation[assetValue_, salvageValue_, 
  assetLife_Integer, depreciationFactor_] := 
 Module[{depreciationRate, bv, n, dep},
  depreciationRate = depreciationFactor/ assetLife;
   (* initialize depTable with year 1 *)
  depTable = {<|
     "year" -> 1,
      "beginningBookValue" -> assetValue,
     "depreciation" -> assetValue  depreciationRate,
     "accumulatedDepreciation" -> assetValue  depreciationRate
     |>};
  (* year counter *)
  n = 1;
  (* loop through years *)
  Until[n > assetLife - 1,
   n++;
   (* new book value *)
   bv = depTable[[n - 1, "beginningBookValue"]] - 
     depTable[[n - 1, "depreciation"]];
   (* tentative depreciation *)
   dep = bv  depreciationRate;
   (* next book value cannot drop below salvage, 
   reduce depreciation if needed *)
   If[
    (dep + depTable[[n - 1, "accumulatedDepreciation"]]) > ( 
      assetValue - salvageValue), 
    dep = - depTable[[n - 1, "accumulatedDepreciation"]] + 
      assetValue - salvageValue
    ];
   (* calculation done for year, add to depTable *)
   AppendTo[  depTable,
    <|
     "year" -> n,
      "beginningBookValue" -> bv,
     "depreciation" -> dep,
     "accumulatedDepreciation" -> 
      depTable[[n - 1, "accumulatedDepreciation"]] + dep
     |>
    ];
   ];
  (* return depTable as Dataset *)
  Dataset@ depTable
  ]

decliningBalanceDepreciation[3000, 500, 5, 2]
```

[image]